# 'ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE' trying to connect to a SQL database (8.2.0) using node.js (v20.10.0)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, socket.io

My First question on stack overflow, and I must say this is a bit of a last resort. I'm trying to complete a school project where I'm making an instant messaging platform using socket.io, express.js and a MySQL database to store and retrieve messages. I run the JS file like normal using node index.js and then get hit with this error:

```
code: 'ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE',
errno: 1251,
sqlMessage: 'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client',
sqlState: '08004',
fatal: true
```

Versions:

- MySQL database 8.2.0
- Node.js v20.10.0
- MySQL workbench 8.0.0 (apparently this is the latest)

OS: Windows

Here is the relevant code for the error:

```js
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const mysql = require('mysql'); // I also tried it with mysql2 

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '1234', //not the actual password 
    database: 'MySQL82',
    port: '3306',
});
db.connect((err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Connected to MySQL database');
});
```

Tried many different ways of fixing it such as Checking that the MySQL package version is up to date.
I also tried to update the mysql server settings

```sql
ALTER USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

but I was unable to do it successfully with the workbench as it would keep giving me errors and then not updating my password for some reason.

I also tried this but it didn't work

```js
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '1234',
    database: 'MySQL82',
    port: '3306',
    authSwitchHandler: (data, callback) => {
        if (data.pluginName === 'caching_sha2_password') {
          callback(null, Buffer.from('YOUR_OLD_PASSWORD')); 
        }
    },
});
```

This is all new stuff to me and I'm pretty much at a complete loss as every effort I make to try and solve the error just results in more issues - and there is definitely the possibility that I'm just being a bit stupid! There were other posts that had similar issues but all the answers that I saw either didn't work for me, was posted many years ago or resulted in an error.

Comment: Updatimg the mysql user's authentication is the best way forwatd at the moment.

Comment: What is the error presented by the `ALTER USER` statement? This needed to be executed as a privileged user, normally `root`.

Comment: Managed to get the alter user statement to work for root but not my actual administrator account which has the same privileges weirdly - also doesn't let me change the password in the users and privileges section for either root or my other accounts as it just returns back to my old set password when I click apply.
Now I'm getting a completely different error:
errno: 1049,
  sqlMessage: "Unknown database 'mysql82'",

Not quite sure why as it definitely exists and it running !